# Route aliasing in ASP.MVC 4

Tags: asp.net, routes, asp.net-mvc-4

Is it possible to alias routes in ASP.NET MVC4 dynamically?

Basically in WebForms I was using something like this:

```
foreach (var rule in rules)
{
    routes.MapPageRoute("_" + rule.Url, rule.Url, rule.Redirect);
}
```

and filling the rules from database.

I need to allow the client to rename routes (or make redirects) from the CMS.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Dynamic route aliasing is a difficult process in ASP.NET MVC to be frank. Creating a single route with a dynamic constraint might be a more elegant solution. This needs to set up a constraint that only matches your categories.

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "Product",
    "{alias}/{pageNumber}",
    new { controller = "Products", action = "Choose", alias = UrlParameter.Optional, pageNumber = 1 },
    new { alias = new ProductOptionCondition() } );
```

The dynamic custom paging in the above is using the dynamic route aliasing option. What have you done exactly. Could you please explain any specific requirement on this, unless its manageable with default route option available with MVC-4.

Comment: Thanks, the thing is we are building the website with dev friendly routes (English, organized, etc) and the client through an admin interface can change those routes to suit their needs say for ~/account/register route he might want an alias ~/register-new-account (but in a different language). All routes need to be dynamic since they might change it quite frequently.

Comment: MVC is using a lot of reflections. And Routing is the process which helps identify your methods. If you re-name or alias any of these methods using reflection then that might be no issue.